# Android APK & Ant: "[aapt] invalid resource directory name"

Tags: android, ant, android-ndk, cygwin, apk

Trying to build an Android APK package, after successfully running `ndk-build` and `android update`, I get the following errors from ant:

```
 [echo] Handling Resources...
 [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
 [aapt] invalid resource directory name: C:\AndroidTestProject\res AndroidManifest.xml
 [aapt] invalid resource directory name: C:\AndroidTestProject\res build.xml
 [aapt] invalid resource directory name: C:\AndroidTestProject\res local.properties
 [aapt] invalid resource directory name: C:\AndroidTestProject\res proguard-project.txt
 [aapt] invalid resource directory name: C:\AndroidTestProject\res project.properties

 BUILD FAILED
```

The "\res" directory and the files mentioned exist and are accessible.

What could possibly be wrong?